# Kendo dropdownlist datatsource sorting

Tags: sorting, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a kendo dropdown in my page using the following list as data source

```
[{FieldOne:'def',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
{FieldOne:'ijk',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
{FieldOne:'lmn',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
{FieldOne:'bcd',FieldTwo:'',FieldThree:14}]
```

I need to sort this data source based on FieldOne ascending and FieldTwo descending
I'm using the following code to sort the data source

```
 var dropdownlist = $("#dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList");
 dropdownlist.dataSource.sort({ field: 'FieldOne', dir: 'asc' });
 dropdownlist.dataSource.sort({ field: 'FieldTwo', dir: 'desc' });
```

Its working fine initially but if I add another object like `{FieldOne:'abc',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14}` to the data source  I'm getting the following result

```
[{FieldOne:'def',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
{FieldOne:'ijk',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
{FieldOne:'lmn',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
{FieldOne:'abc',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
{FieldOne:'bcd',FieldTwo:'',FieldThree:14}]
```

but I want the datasource sorted as

```
[{FieldOne:'abc',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
{FieldOne:'def',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
{FieldOne:'ijk',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
{FieldOne:'lmn',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
{FieldOne:'bcd',FieldTwo:'',FieldThree:14}]
```

I don't know how to achieve this I tried almost everything I know but still no result. Is there anyway that I can get the desired result???

Comment: Maybe you have to sort everytime you add an object...

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown currently I'm doing that but no effect

Answer (score 2):

You shoud define sorting in dataSource:

```
<input id="dropdownlist" />
<script>
  var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource:{
      data:[{FieldOne:'def',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
        {FieldOne:'ijk',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
        {FieldOne:'lmn',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14},
        {FieldOne:'bcd',FieldTwo:'',FieldThree:14}],
      sort: [
        { field: "FieldOne", dir: "asc" },
        { field: "FieldTwo", dir: "desc" }
      ]
    },
    dataTextField: "FieldOne",
    dataValueField: "FieldTwo"
  }).data('kendoDropDownList');

  dropdownlist.dataSource.add({FieldOne:'abc',FieldTwo:'p',FieldThree:14});
</script>
```

check http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-sort for more info